# Fiat panda 1.1 2009 cigarette lighter

Tags: fiat, panda

I am trying to fit a cigarette lighter on fiat panda 1.1 2009. The loom and socket is under the bezel by cup holder. There is no power at socket.I was told i need to put fuse and relay in the engine compartment fusebox but I dont know where abouts in the fusebox the fuse and relay belong. Could you please help?

Comment: Unfortunately the engine fuse box is different for exo version (without power outlet) and adding fuse and relay won't work as there is no connections under it. :( So it's only "DIY" way...

Answer (score 2):

According to [page 165](https://manuals.co/workshop/fiat/panda/fiat-panda-2009-owners-manual/2980764/166) of the owner's manual, there is a 20 amp fuse (F85) and a 30 amp replay (T31) required. These are located in the fuse box in the engine compartment.

On [page 162](https://manuals.co/workshop/fiat/panda/fiat-panda-2009-owners-manual/2980764/163) of the Owner's Manual, is figure 169, it shows the location of the fuse and the relay.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have just had this issue with my Nieces Panda.
Bought the kit, wiring loom and socket were there so I thought it was going to be a simple plug and play but no power. 
Checked the fuse box and inserted the missing fuse but still no power.
Took the fuse box out of its holder to discover that the Blue/Black wire is not connected to F85 so the wire from the cigarette lighter socket must deadend somewhere.
There is power to the Red/Yellow wire but only when the lights are on which is obviously just for the light on the socket.
As my Neice is not a smoker and only wants it to charge her phone and plug in a Bluetooth device I might just use that swapping it with the Bule/black in the plug until I have time to run a fresh wire in.